# Prevent site inside <iframe> from responding / acting responsively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am displaying some sites in `<iframes>` in my site and those sites, which I don't have control over the source of, are responding / acting responsively inside the `<iframe>`.

Is there a way I can prevent this?

By acting responsively, I mean they are sized at their largest breakpoint bigger than what the `<iframe>` is and they don't fit within the `<iframe>`.

Comment: Finish your sentences please. inside the (?) fit within (?)

Comment: @Ceres The OP forgot to surround HTML tags by backticks, causing content to be dropped. See the edit.

Comment: @Ceres oops sorry about that.